# Textbox.io: Can change color for UI toolbar?

Tags: javascript, uitoolbar, rich-text-editor, textboxio

I am currently testing on different text editor system for my company website. I have just downloaded the text editor, TextBox.io but i want to change the UI colour toolbar as I want the editor to blends in with my website well. Could anybody help me please?

[TextBox.io editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38XC0.png)

Regards,

Nuriin

Comment: why don't you just change the css style?

Comment: as in i want to change the toolbar colour instead of the background text box. I do not want it to be in black colour. Btw thanks for the suggestion samayo

Comment: @NuriinABMZ I have added below some of the classes that you have to change in order to change the color.

Comment: @miquelarranz Thanks for the ans. Will do test on it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.0 of Textbox.io includes a supported way to change the UI colours. We have greatly simplified the colour specification from our previous release down to a handful of variables. There is no longer any need to override our CSS as in the answer from @miquelarranz.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest solution is to change the css manually. So using your browser inspector search the div that contains the style and force it to be the color you want.

I think that the style is this one:

```
.ephox-polish-editor-container .ephox-chameleon-toolstrip {
    background-color: yourcolor !important; // I am not sure if you will need !important
}
```

And if you want to change the shadow:

```
.ephox-polish-editor-container .ephox-chameleon-toolbar:first-child {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -.5em 1em yourcolor !important; // I am not sure if you will need !important
}
```

You may need to change more styles probably depending of what you want to do, but I hope it may help you to understand how to change the colors.